# Project Reactor - how to process results by window

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have following Flux:

```
Flux.range(0, 100)
    .log("before window")
    .window(10)
    .map(Flux::toList)
    .log("after window")
    .map((w) -> {
        System.out.println(w.subscribe().get()));
        return 1;
    }) 
    .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b)
    .doOnSuccess(System.out::println)
    .subscribe();
```

I thought in `doOnNext` I should be able to get block of items for this moment. But `.get` always fails with `Timeout on Mono blocking read` excpeption.

I see from log, all had processed before `.window`, and resulting log gives:

```
[           main] before window : onNext(0)
[           main] after window  : onNext({ operator : "BufferAll" })
```

There're not so much information in official docs, so I guess I misunderstand something, and using `window` function incorrectly. But what exactly I'm doing wrong here?

UPDATE

I figured out that this particular problem can be avoided if I use `.doOnSuccess` instead. Like:

```
.map((w) -> {
    w.doOnSuccess((w2) -> System.out.println(w2))).subscribe();
    return 1;
}
```

but the real issue, that at my case I need to return a number from based on some calculations against provided data (instead of `1`). I can create a new `Mono` here, but anyway, later I should `.get` it. For example in final `.reduce`. So if I do `.reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b.get())` it will fail there then.

How I can safely get value from a Mono?

UPDATE 2

Now I've remove Flux:toList and do it by myself, returning `Mono` from mapping phase after window. That's probably how it should be.

```
.window(10)
.log("after window")
.map((w) -> {
    //basically i'm reducing Flux to a Mono<List> and return number of a [good] elements in it
    return w.reduce(...).map(ids -> 100).subscribe();
})
.reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b.get())
```

But it doesn't work anyway, stuck in `.reduce`:

Noticed that if I remove `.reduce` step, it works. At this case processing of the `Flux` provided by `.window` are executed *after* main flow. I don't have any control over it, and even can't get final result. Which doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was because I need to reduce *window* before further usage.

Like:

```
window(...).flatMap( (window) -> window.reduce(...))
```

I was doing that inside a Mono in my mapper, but it blocks execution flow there, so it isn't a right place. It must be after window, before next usage.

Correct version is:

```
Flux.range(0, 100)
    .window(10)
    .flatMap(window -> {
         return window.reduce(new ArrayList<>(), (a, b) -> {
             a.add(b);
             return a;
         });
    })
    .map((list) -> list.size())
    .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b)
    .doOnSuccess(System.out::println)
    .subscribe();
```

I'm converting window to a `List`, and then I can use this value in following operations.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking at this recently. The `.window(3)` function turns it into a flux of fluxes. This can, I think, be processed neatly by doing a nested subscribe. The `.buffer()` function converts the flux into a list when the window is `onComplete()`.

This bit of code was the breakthrough for me...

```
Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.range(1, 10).log();

flux
  .doOnNext(s -> logger.info("pre-window:{}", s))
  .window(3)
  .subscribe(s -> s.log().buffer().subscribe(t -> logger.info("post-window:{}", t)));
```

Also, simply using `.buffer(3)` appears to produce similar if not identical results...

```
flux
    .doOnNext(s -> logger.info("pre-buffer:{}", s))
    .buffer(3)
    .subscribe(t -> logger.info("post-buffer:{}", t));
```

Hope that helps!